# three.js transparent material issue

Tags: three.js

I have set a transparent map, though, not all parts are transparent.

I'm using a transparent PNG image as the material map, though it shows background as seen here:

[image]
[image]

material:

```
new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: texture, transparent: true, alphaTest: 0})
```

renderer:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true});
renderer.preserveDrawingBuffer   = true;
renderer.premultipliedAlpha = false;
```

Comment: Indented the code instead of making it a quote and made images visible.

Comment: try `alphaTest: 0.5`